# Calling setStatusBarColor ANDROID

Tags: java, android, statusbar, buttonclick

How can I call setStatusBarColor on a buttonclick? I have the event listener code but I'm unsure how to call this method. I'm trying to change the status bar color on button click.

Here's my code:

```
public static void setStatusBarColor(Activity activity, int statusBarColor) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    // If both system bars are black, we can remove these from our layout,
                    // removing or shrinking the SurfaceFlinger overlay required for our views.
                    Window window = activity.getWindow();
                    if (statusBarColor == Color.BLACK && window.getNavigationBarColor() == Color.BLACK) {
                        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
                    } else {
                        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
                    }
                    window.setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#4CAF50"));
                }
            }
```

Here is my button listener

```
public void addButtonListener() {

        Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button);
        Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                setStatusBarColor();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain what's not working ?

Comment: Show at least the listener code on your button.

Comment: Apologies @ci_ . I'm trying to call it with setStatusBarColor();

Comment: @user1353517 it seems like you didn't edit your question, plz clearly explain what's going on

Comment: @HugoGresse I'm trying to call setStatusBarColor(); inside my button click. but it's giving me the error "setStatusBarColor (Activity, int) in main Activity cannot be applied to () "

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your method call to this

**In Activity**

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    setStatusBarColor(this, Color.parseColor("#4CAF50"));
}
```

**In Fragment:**

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    setStatusBarColor(getActivity() , Color.parseColor("#4CAF50"));  
}
```

**Or remove the parameter from method**

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    setStatusBarColor();  
} 

public static void setStatusBarColor() {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        // If both system bars are black, we can remove these from our layout,
        // removing or shrinking the SurfaceFlinger overlay required for our views.


        //change here
         Window window = activity.getWindow();

        // By -->>>>> Window window = getWindow();

        //or by this if call in Fragment
        // -->>>>> Window window = getActivity().getWindow();


        int statusBarColor = Color.parseColor("#4CAF50");

        if (statusBarColor == Color.BLACK && window.getNavigationBarColor() == Color.BLACK) {
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        } else {
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        }
        window.setStatusBarColor(statusBarColor);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried removing the parameter from the method but i'm faced with "cannot resolve symbol 'activity'" and "cannot resolve symbol statusBarColor

Comment: I also tried the second way and i'm faced with cannot resolve method getActivity() and the first way says it cannot be applied

Comment: it cannot be referenced from static context. statusBarColor in the if statement throws a cannot resolve symbol error as well :/

Comment: I'm still faced with the status bar color error. Changing it to getWindow() works if I change it to public void.

Comment: can you remove static from your method public void setStatusBarColor()

Comment: That fixed it. I have an error in the if statement on statusBarColor. It shows cannot resolve symbol

Comment: This works :D Thanks so much for the help. I've accepted the answer